# Javascript functions won't echo

Tags: php, javascript, function, loading

I have a php file with some javascript code in it, and i'm calling the file using the script tags in my HTML. My problem is when I have a get method in the php, the java function won't echo..here's my code:

```
Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");

        $monthS = $_GET['location'];

     // Connect to MySQL
         if ( !( $database = mysql_connect( "localhost",
            "root", "" ) ) )                      
            die( "Could not connect to database </body></html>" );

    // open Events database
         if ( !mysql_select_db( "Events", $database ) )
            die( "Could not open Events database </body></html>" );


            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posted_events WHERE Month_ = 'July' ") 
                    or die ('Error updating database because: '.mysql_error());;


            $daysArray = Array();
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                $daysArray[] =  $row['DayNum']; }
            $length = count($daysArray);

            echo "function test() { ";
                echo "alert('monthS');";
                for($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) { 
            echo "var active = document.getElementById('day'+".$daysArray[$i].");
             active.setAttribute('class', active.getAttribute('class') + ' event');  ";
}       
            echo "}";
```

But if i remove `$monthS = $_GET['location'];`then the function echos perfectly, but i need that variable. And I got that variable from JS using JQuery.

Comment: What this code is doing is horrible. It advertises that it will generate Javascript (with the wrong MIME type), and then on error spits out a mix of plain text and HTML (neither of which is valid Javascript). Of course if any (human-readable) error output gets generated, for example an "undefined index $_GET[location]", that will also break the output. Please consider all these problems and revisit the code to make it tighter.

Comment: Turn on error reporting and see what messages appear.  It's likely that you're not actually setting `location` correctly.  You could test with something like `print_r($_GET)` or [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

Comment: Is `$_GET['location']` passed? Are you getting a PHP notice which is causing your output to be messed up?  By the way, you don;t seem to be using the variable properly where you are trying to output it into the `alert()`.  You are just outputting a literal string of `monthS` not a variable.

Comment: if i were to alert the get variable, it alerts, so I guess it passed

Answer (score 3):

Be **VERY** careful with this type of code. You're directly generating Javascript. **ANY** warnings or stray output from PHP will probably introduce syntax errors into the code, causing the JS interpreter to kill the entire script block.

You'd be better off generating some data that goes to pre-written Javascript, which can then work on the data,  e.g.

```
$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
   $data[] = $row;
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;

for (i in data) {
   ... do stuff with javascript data array
}
```

as it stands now, if you don't have a `location` parameter in the url for this script, you'll probably get a PHP warning about an undefined array key. That warning will become part of the JS code, and be treated as a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to echo the PHP Get variable into javascript to assign the js variable.

```
echo "<script>var varmonthS = " . $_GET['location'] . ";";
echo "alert(varmonthS);</script>";
```

Comment: but i want to assign the js variable to a php

Comment: I don't think you can do that.  PHP server side code runs before the JS client side code runs.

Comment: yea I realized that now. Any way i could make this possible?